# CLLocationManager time format?

Tags: nsdateformatter, cllocationmanager

I have an app that saves a user's location to a backend database, and then later reads these in for use elsewhere.

I am getting and saving the location timestamp to my server using the following code:

```
CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
currentLocation.timestamp // this is the timestamp I save to the database.
```

Later on, I read this back in, but I am having trouble formatting this back to a useable date object.

My code is:

```
    NSLog(@"time from server = %@", item.timestamp);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *savedTime = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    savedTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:item.timestamp];
    NSLog(@"time formatted = %@", savedTime);
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
time from server = 2015-07-05 13:32:36  0000
time formatted = (null)
```

Can anyone help get this "time formatted" output working?

Is it because the setDateFormat is not correct? I am not sure what the '0000' at the end of the 'time from server' is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this as your format:

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"
```

This now works fine for me:

[image]

> This is swift in the picture, but the important part is the date format string.  That is language independent and I just wanted to show you that it was working.  Replacing the format string in ObjC will work just fine.

Comment: Perfect - was just the "zzz" I was missing!